# Handling conditions in blade templates on laravel 4 in a form input

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to test the existence of value in blade on Laravel 4.

Like:

```
{{ Form::text('name', @if(isset($value)) {{$value}} @endif; }}
```

I tried this:

```
{{ Form::text('name', @if(isset($value)) $value @endif; }}
```

Comment: If `$value` is unset it will not be rendered on the input.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in one line.

I'd prefer a better approach, using `condition?if:else` , which also I use in my daily projects:

```
{{ Form::text('name',isset($value)?$value:'') }}
```

or even:

```
{{ Form::text('name',isset($value)?$value:null) }}
```

Comment: Blade just converts "{{" to "<?php echo" so you can use PHP as much as you like within.

Comment: It's what I am going to do. tx

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere before that, you can add the line `<?php if(!isset($value)) { $value= ''; } ?>`.  Then you can proceed as usual `{{ Form::text('name', $value) }}`

Comment: YEs, I agree with this. If can't do it directly in the the declaration of input field. thank you

Comment: @Mamadou You can do it in one line. No need to open a <?php tag. Please see my answer.